# DropDownListFor - Set value via jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a .Net Core web application with a DropDownListFor. I have an AJAX function that checks if the customer has a profile on the legacy system and then autofill the values. This is working great, but when setting the value of a dropdownlist, the Model Value is always 0.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryId, CountryService.List().Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Id.ToString(), Text = c.Name }), "select", new { @class = "form-control input-wide input-required" })
```

Ajax function

```
$("#CountryId").val(countryId).change();
$("#CountryId").val(countryId); //tried both
```

This sets the value of the drop down, but when hitting save, the model property for CountryId is always 0. If the profile isn't found and the customer registers and selected the Country manually, it works as expected. It is almost as if the model doesn't notice the change?

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that generated id is `CountryId`? and `.val()` should work

Comment: can you share your ajax call. plus what are you setting in `CountryId`?

Comment: found the problem. I was setting the dropdown as disabled after setting the value. I did this to prevent the user from changing the value. It seems disabled doesn't post the value to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

The data you are passing to the DropdownListFor, must matching type and exist in the initial list, otherwise sets on default value.

Lets take an example, if your binding data for your DropdownListFor is SelectItem, then you have to pass type of text and value, if its object(class) you have to pass key/value of property of the object, and the data must exist in the list, i.e. if your initiate list is 1,2,3,4, but you passing 5, then it cant find.